# The controls cloned in jQuery gets erased on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a button(Button1) in a div element.
Another button(Button2) outside that div may be in another div, on click of Button2  the other div gets cloned using jQuery "clone()" method.
Each time i click on the button(Button2) the new div element with the button gets cloned with all its events.

Example :

```
$(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("#divHello").clone(true).appendTo("#divBye");
        });
    });
```

The Button1 is attached with event Click to write its ID to the page.
But the problem is that on click of Button2 the  with Button1 get clonned as many times the button clicked but when the Button2 is clicked altheough it writes the ID to page but all other clonned div elements get erased which should not be as per my requirement.

If any one is having solution for it please help.

Comment: The HTML would be helpful. I'm getting a headache trying to visualize all the elements. ;-)

Comment: You're creating DIVs in the client browser. When the page reloads, the server sends the normal page (without the cloned DIVs, because the server doesn't know about them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right! You are creating elements on the client side, when you reload the page, the server sends back what it has, that does not include the elements you created on the client.